# How to sort list by sub list value in flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, flutter, dart

I am a flutter developer and I want help to fix that problem

I have an array and I want to sort it

below is the structure of this list:

```
List myList = [
  {
     'name': 'Max',
     'messages': [
       {
        'time': 133459086,
        'text': 'Hello World!',  
       }
     ],
  },
  {
     'name': 'Wax',
     'messages': [
       {
        'time': 133459083,
        'text': 'Hello !',  
       }
     ],
  },
];
```

I want to sort that myList by descending using the time value in messages.

Note: the messages array could be empty so it could throw an error with bad state no element.

please help me,

Thanks,

Comment: Please fix your code so it will have a valid object structure. Right now 'messages' is invalid.

Comment: sorry fixed it,

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer:

```
myList.sort((a,b) => b['messages'].isNotEmpty ? b['messages'].last['time'].compareTo(a['messages'].isNotEmpty ? a['messages'].last['time'] : 0 ) : 0,);
```

Answer (score 1):

That data is invalid currently.

If the `messages` node is an array, then its items need to be wrapped in objects, something like:

```
'messages': [
  {
    'time': 133459089,
    'text': 'Hello!'
  }
]
```

If thats the case, you need to know if there will only ever be one message item in `messages` or if there can be multiple.

Comment: what's the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var list = myList..sort((b, a) => a['messages']['time'].compareTo(b['messages']['time']));

print(list);
```

Comment: sorry, messages is an array